# How do I determine the length of a list in RedDot/OpenText?

Tags: content-management-system, reddot

I have a page with a list element attached. How do I determine the number of items in that list? Can use render tags, asp, or any other technique (so long as it works!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the render tags documentation I believe it may be possible to do this in a nicer way

So getting the list Element using this

> Context:CurrentPage.Elements.GetElement(lst_myPages).Value

The Value property should return a page collection for list items so you should be able to do

> Context:CurrentPage.Elements.GetElement(lst_myPages).Value.Count

Comment: An old thread...but the modern, more efficient way to do this is `Context:Pages.GetPage(Guid:<%inf_GUID%>).GetElementByName(lst_myPages).Value.Count` (where inf_GUID is the page GUID)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!IoRangePreExecute>
  <% lst_myPagesSize = 0 %>

  <!IoRangeList>
    <% lst_myPagesSize = lst_myPagesSize + 1%>
    <!IoRangeRedDotMode><!--[if !IE]><%lst_myPages%><![endif]--><!/IoRangeRedDotMode>  
  <!/IoRangeList>

<!/IoRangePreExecute>
```

I think this is the fastest way.
First counter = 0. Then in the list range increment the counter (keep in mind to include the list place-holder too in that block). After that you have the value in the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the only way to do this is to loop through the list, counting each item, e.g.

```
<reddot:cms>
<foreach itemname="testList"
         object="Context:CurrentPage.Elements.GetElement(lst_myPages).Value"
         countername="listCounter">
</foreach>
</reddot:cms>
```

The length is then available as:

```
<%!! Store:listCounter !!%>
```

Comment: Would be great if someone could confirm this (or, even better, come up with a proper way of finding the length!)

Comment: <%!! Store:listCounter !!%> gives the position on the loop (0,1,2..)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenText use this render tag to get the length of a list (name of list element: lst_Navigation):

```
<%!! Context:CurrentPage.GetElementByName(lst_Navigation).GetLinkedContents().Count !!%>
```

Context/RDObj: by ObjectLoader Context (alias: RDObj) you get access to objects of Management Server

CurrentPage: returns Page objekt from current page

GetElementByName: method from page object to get a page element by name

GetLinkedContents: returns a LinkList object

Count: returns the number of LinkList elements

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26925589)

Comment: @SurajBahadur Its actually the best answer. Since Object Linklist does not have a property called Value at least in OpenText version >= 11.